# How do I get data from a foreign table to a related controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller, foreign-keys, inertiajs

I have two tables Bio and Govap, Govap has a foreignId reference to Bio, In the GovapController, i want to pass the data from Bio table to Govap table and have it render on the frontend using Inertia and Vue.

I tried the following and received error:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated=$request->validate([
    'department'=>['required'],
    'unit'=>['required'],
    'type_of_appointment'=>['required'],
    'date_of_first_app'=>['required'],
    'designation_post'=>['required'],
    'salary_per_annum_at_date_of_first_app'=>['required'],
    'salary_scale'=>['required'],
    'grade_level'=>['required'],
    'step'=>['required']
    ]);
    $request->bio()->govap()->create($validated);
    return redirect(route('gov.index'));
}
```

This is the error message:

> BadMethodCallException
> Method Illuminate\Http\Request::bio does not exist.**

Here is my model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'department',
    'unit',
    'date_of_first_app',
    'type_of_appointment',
    'designation_post',
    'salary_per_annum_at_date_of_first_app',
    'salary_scale',
    'grade_level',
    'step',
];

public function bio(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Bio::class);
}
```

here are the routes:

```
Route::resource('gov', GovapController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'store','update','destroy'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

Comment: If you are passing model bio to this method, then you should retrieve it as another parameter and not from request

Comment: please show me an example

Comment: Add your route file with the route store() please

Comment: Route::resource('gov', GovapController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'store','update','destroy'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);

Comment: Thank you, could you also share both models code? You can edit your question and add code in it

Comment: Alright, it is done

Comment: Okay, so you are trying to get `bio` model from request, do you actually pass it? If yes, try to remove brackets from `->bio()` in your store method

Comment: How do i pass it please, I am kinda new to Laravel

Comment: You are probably trying to achieve [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: Why are you accessing `bio()` method of a model from the `Request` object. Just instantiate the model and access the method using it's object.

Comment: I did that and I receive an error “bio_id doesn’t have a default value”